# Can someone provide an proof for $E[P[A|X]] = P[A]$

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation

I'm tired of seeing the word "trivial" for this equality on every single lecture notes I could find online. Can someone please show me why this is indeed trivial?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(It's difficult to know what level you want this pitched at. In attempting to straddle the territory a bit, I may not successfully hit it here.)

I'll show the continuous-x case; more general cases are very similar.

\begin{eqnarray}
E[P(A|X)] &=& \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(a|x)\cdot f(x)\, dx\\
 &=& \int_{-\infty}^\infty  f(a,x)\, dx \\
 &=& P(A)
\end{eqnarray}

---

In the context (from comments), we're effectively trying to show
$$\Pr(A)=\sum_n \Pr(A| X=x_n)\Pr(X=x_n) = \text{E}[\Pr(A| X)] ,$$
(the first half of which is simply the [law of total probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability#Applications), and the second half of which is just definition of expectation), but starting from
$$\text{E}(Y) = \text{E}_X(\text{E}_{Y | X} ( Y | X)),$$
(the [law of total expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation)) by letting $Y=1_A$:
$$\text{E}(1_A) = \text{E}_X(\text{E}_{1_A | X} (1_A | X)),$$
which is just
$$\text{P}(A) = \text{E}_X(\text{P}(A | X))\,.$$

Comment: Hi, my misconception is that $P(A|X)$ cannot be $f(a|x)$, because $E[P(A|X)] = \int P(A|X) fX(x) dx$, and what you did up there is essentially replacing $P(A|X)$ with $f(a|x)$, then it would be as if saying the pdf itself is the probability

Comment: That's probably a matter of being clear what is meant by $P(A|X)$; in a given context it's easier to give a more concrete demonstration. The essential issue here is how the definition of expectation comes into the relationship between the conditional and joint, and then "integrating" (in the more general sense) the resulting joint to obtain the marginal. There are a number of ways to show this. If you give an explicit situation it's usually easy to give the demonstration directly in terms of how that situation is set up.

Comment: If A is discrete, then $f(a|x)$ is a discrete pmf. (If $X$ is also discrete, then $f(x)$ is a discrete pmf and the integral is a sum; we can cover all such combinations by more general arguments, but the nature of the question had me unsure about whether to be more specific or more general, or even precisely what's intended by $P(A|X)$ (whether you're really dealing with a specific event $A$, or a conditional probability function).

Comment: I'm equally confused as this is generally how this question is stated. Would it help if it was written as $E[P(Y=A|X)]$ or $E[P(X=A|X)]$?

Comment: That would seem to confuse things much more. If you give a specific context where you've seen it stated I can try to suit the demonstration better to the context and it may speak to you more clearly. My concern was more whether $A$ is a specific event or a random variable.

Comment: Hi thank you. One instance can be found on bullet 13 of this link: http://www.randomservices.org/random/expect/Conditional.html, it would also be helpful if you can help me decipher what they meant by "direct result"

Comment: By 'direct result of' means that it's an immediate consequence of the [law of total expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) -- by taking $Y=\mathbf{1}_A$, you get (effectively) this result of the [law of total probability‌](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability#Applications)​. Those links might be enough to cover you. I may come back and edit my answer to reflect that context, but in the meantime hopefully they make it clear.

Comment: Answer updated.